# Coroutines bug in android with Kotlin 1.6

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-studio-3.0

I just updated the kotlin from 1.5 to 1.6, and this function

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Noticia")
suspend fun selectAll() :List<Noticia>
```

gives me the following error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.lang.Object).
public abstract java.lang.Object selectAll(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

I guess is because of the new release of kotlin but I'm not sure

Comment: remove `suspend` from defination

Comment: Try to Clean project and then Rebuild project

Comment: I tried all of this and didn't work, when I remove the suspend from the function gives me this error:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an outdated room versión, all I did was change the room versión to this:

```
    def room_version = "2.3.0"
```